# Undefined method `b64encode' for Base64:Module - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encode

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Hi,
I want to encode a string whose length is more than default 60. Therefore, I can't use the **Base64.encode64** method.

From the following link - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

I got to know about **b64encode(bin, len = 60)** method. But on using, it shows the error -

```
in `<top (required)>': undefined method `b64encode' for Base64:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Where am I making the mistake.

PS - The version of Ruby for me is `ruby 2.3.0p0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Base64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) has no method `b64encode`. You are reading the documentation for Ruby 1.8.7, which was released in 2008 and [retired in 2013](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/).

The available method for encoding is `Base64.encode64`.

Comment: Please do not alter the question after it is answered, as it will make it very confusing. If you have a different problem, open a new question. You should rollback this one to the original question, and mark it as answered.